# Referencing [weak self] as self? inside animateWithDuration causes crash

Tags: swift, memory-management, option-type

If I declare `[weak self]` on a closure and reference `self` as `self?` inside `UIView.animateWithDuration` the app will crash:

```
someFunc() { [weak self] (success) -> Void in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
        self?.someView.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

with a `message sent to deallocated instance`

but if I optionally unwrap self ahead of time it doesn't

```
someFunc() { [weak self] (success) -> Void in
    if let weakself = self {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
            weakself.someView.alpha = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that, I would think that it doesn't matter which way I reference the weak self since it should "just" optionally unwrap `self?` correctly.  For context this is done in a `UICellView` which is deallocated when I leave the `UICollectionViewController`

**EDIT:** Filed a bug with apple: #23492648

Comment: This is actually really weird, smells like a bug to me. Btw what's up with the unnecessary `;`? Are you calling a function or is this a property?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited it for clarity instead of `doSomething`.  I pushed for using `;` in our codebase because it makes the end of statements unambiguous.  There are situations where you could have a statement wrap a line and its not super obvious :)

Comment: This is a good bug report, and you should report it to Apple. But it is _also_ true that you should always do the weak-strong dance when passing things weakly into an anonymous function, as you do in the second example (`if let weakself = self`), so just do it and move on.

Comment: Why always do the `if let weakself = self` dance, `self?` should just do its optional magic shouldn't it?

Comment: It's no use talking about "should", @Shizam. There is only "is". You've brilliantly shown what is. Accept that and move on. File the bug report just in case, though!

Comment: Very zen, doing just that :thumbsup:

Comment: might want share the bug id? Lesson learned.

Comment: Can do, radar bug 23492648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `self` is special. You've passed the reference to `self` weakly into the anonymous function to prevent a retain cycle, but there isn't really an Optional wrapping `self` in this story. Thus, the syntactic sugar `self?.someView.alpha = 1` — and remember, it *is* merely syntactic sugar — doesn't work.

It may be that Apple will regard this as a bug; or maybe not. But either way, the solution is to do formulaically exactly what you are doing in the second example: do the weak-strong dance *explicitly*.